# How to block incoming connections by source address in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, firewall

Can the Windows Firewall in Windows Server be used to block connections from a specific IP address?

Comment: Please expand on the reason and application.

Comment: Seems clear enough to me although I did ask for more specific info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 7, the Firewall control panel allows the creation of very specific rules through the "Advanced Settings".  On the Inbound Rule tab, there is a New Rule wizard, and IP addresses can be specified in the scope section and "block" specified as the action to take. A rule to block all incoming connections from a specific IP address or range is possible.

On Windows XP, the Firewall control panel allows the blocking on incoming requests from specific programs, and each program can have the block only for a certain IP range (via the "scope" button on the dialog to add a program).  With a bit more specific info I imagine it can be configured to do what blocking you need.

I don't know which Windows Firewall is on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: The Firewall on 2008 is the same as Vista (with a few minor differences); Just as 2008 R2 is basically the same as Win7.

Comment: I scrupulously avoided Vista, so I couldn't address it!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it indeed does.

Comment: +1, 2008: Open the Firewall Snap-In, right click Inbound Rules, Add rule. Custom. All Programs. Any protocol type. Specify the remote IP(s). Block Connection. Next, name it, Finish. 2003 is more difficult, it's easiest to block everything by default and allow known good IPs in.

Answer (score -2):

The Windows Firewall on Windows Server 2003 does not give you options to create IP-specific rules.  The firewall on Server 2008 has been updated to allow blocking by IP.  You CAN do this using the IP Security Policy snap-in for MMC, however, in Server 2003.

Open MMC and add the "IP Security Policy" snap-in and create a new policy.  You will need to create an IP list which contains the addresses you want to block, and an action list to specify the block action.  Add a new policy rule which uses the IP list and the block action list, then activate (assign) it.  The addresses on the policy list will then be blocked from connecting to the server.

This web site also has a good overview of the process:  http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/ip-security-ipsec2/ipsec-packet-filtering.aspx

Comment: -1, You can definitely create a rule in the Windows Firewall where a remote IP is specified. You can also block by range, and certain pre-defined sets. IP Security Policy will also accomplish this, but it not the first place everyone is going to look.

Comment: The firewall on Windows Server 2003 does not give this option.  Apparently the firewall on Server 2008 has been updated to allow this.